# multiple column subquery for update statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following update statement

```
UPDATE mytable
    set tmax = (
                SELECT tmax
                FROM myvalues
                WHERE Longitude_MAX >= v_lng and 
                      STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = v_date
                      limit 1),
        tmin = (
                SELECT tmin
                FROM myvalues
                WHERE Longitude_MAX >= v_lng and 
                      STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = v_date
                      limit 1),    
    where pkid = v_pkid;
```

its working but very slow, can we optimize it?

there are some example on net, but these join the both tables and have no such join.

Comment: what JOIN? Do I need to join both tables?

Comment: You need to join one table to the other table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that with JOIN

```
   UPDATE mytable  mt
   INNER JOIN myvalues mv
   ON STR_TO_DATE(mv.Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = mt.accident_dt
   SET mt.tmax = mv.tmax , mt.tmin=mv.tmin
   WHERE Longitude_MAX >= v_lng 
   and STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = v_date
   AND pkid = v_pkid;
```

Comment: dear echo_Me "ON mv.tmax = mt.tmax" the mt.tmax is null, so this will not update the table.

Comment: I think only mt.transaction_date and mv.date can be join.

Comment: you right, then you need to make ON condition with the relation between the two tables.

Comment: you have no relation between tables ?

Comment: Before edit the above answer solve the problem, I changed the ON to ON STR_TO_DATE(mv.Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = mt.accident_dt               UPDATE mytable  mt
   INNER JOIN myvalues mv
   ON STR_TO_DATE(mv.Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = mt.accident_dt
   SET mt.tmax = mv.tmax , mt.tmin=mv.tmin
   WHERE Longitude_MAX >= v_lng 
   and STR_TO_DATE(Date, '%m/%d/%Y') = v_date
   AND pkid = v_pkid;

Comment: dear #echo_Me can you enter the previous statement before the edit?